# Safe way to encrypt a network application

Tags: java, security, aes, rsa, netty

Alright, I'd like to know my current way to encrypt a network connection(will be explained in the next few lines) is safe and efficient.

Also I'm trying to keep in mind that I want to use as less bytes(to transfer) as possible, as this might be used for Android.

My current way is by using the two encryption methods: RSA(keysize= 512) and AES(keysize= 128)

What I did is:

1. Server generates an RSA Public Key and a Private Key.
2. When a client connects, the server sends the Public RSA Key to the client.
3. The client generates an AES Key and encrypts the AES Key using the public RSA Key provided by the server.
4. The client sends his encrypted AES Key and the server decrypts the encrypted AES Key using the Private RSA Key.

Now if I am correct it's impossible to sniff any packets from the client side as you can't possibly decrypt the AES Key(no private key).

Is this a secure way? Or is there some sort of backdoor somewhere?

This isn't my only question though;

Because my application is built in Java, it's always possible to reverse engineer it. Since the client generates the AES Key and saves it in memory, is it possible to get hold of the AES Key?

Final question:
It takes me around 300ms to generate a keypair using this code:

I'd like your people's opinions and/or improvements.

```
private RSAKeySet(RSAPublicKey publicKey, PrivateKey privateKey) {
    this.publicKey = publicKey;
    this.privateKey = privateKey;

    byte[] mod = publicKey.getModulus().toByteArray();
    byte[] exp = publicKey.getPublicExponent().toByteArray();

    localPublicKeySpec = ByteBuffer.allocate(mod.length + exp.length + 8);
    localPublicKeySpec.putInt(mod.length);
    localPublicKeySpec.put(mod);
    localPublicKeySpec.putInt(exp.length);
    localPublicKeySpec.put(exp);
    localPublicKeySpec.flip();
}

public static final RSAKeySet generateKeys(int keySize) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    RSAKeySet set;
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");

    kpg.initialize(keySize);
    KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
    set = new RSAKeySet((RSAPublicKey) kp.getPublic(), kp.getPrivate());

    System.err.println("RSA keys generated (" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms)");
    return set;
}
```

I'm using Netty, is 300ms affordable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this isn't secure - your scheme is broken at step #1, as you have no way to guarantee that the public key you receive was generated by the server, or by a man-in-the-middle intercepting traffic and either eavesdropping, or altering the data before sending it on to the real server.

The second problem is that a 512 bit RSA key is far too small to be secure. A single modern desktop PC can factor such a key in less than a month, and with multiple machines could probably be brought down to days/hours. Whilst you're generating a new key each time, someone could still easily record traffic and then factor the keys offline if they only needed to eavesdrop the connection.

With regards accessing the AES key in-memory, yes that's entirely possible, however anyone with access to the client process' memory also has access to the plaintext data prior to it being encrypted at all. This is something that's going to be an issue regardless the particular encryption method used, though ensuring that the keys do not persist in memory beyond their period of use will limit the period during which such an attack is possible. This is however somewhat more difficult to achieve in something like Java where the GC could move data around and leave multiple copies of a key in memory even if you zero the key data after use.

In summary, I'd strongly suggest that you don't try and invent your own crypto scheme, but instead use an existing, well established, and proven scheme such as SSL. My expertise isn't Java, but I would be pretty certain that the means to establish an SSL session exists within the API.

Comment: Thanks, opened my eyes. I'd vote up but I don't have enough reputation.